# How do you prove the left and right side of an identity of a set are equal?

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations, associativity

I'm having some trouble understanding sets w/ associative binary operations. Say I have a set "S" w/ the associative binary operation SxS -> S. If 'L' is a left identity of S and 'R' is a right identity of S, how can I prove those two are equal?

The definition of associativity is for all a, b, c in G, we have (a * b) * c = a * (b * c). But how does that apply to proving they are equal? It seems obvious but I'm sure there's a certain "proof" way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is the proof.

$$ L =  L * R = R$$

No need to use associativity.

---

For an elaboration.

A left identity is an element $L$ satisfying $L * g = g$ for every $g \in G$. Hence $L * R = R$.

A right identity is an element satisfying $g * R = g \;\; \forall g \in G$. Hence, $L * R = L$.

Comment: so even if it says it is a set w/ an associative binary operation *: SxS -> S, that doesn't affect the left/right identities of the set?

Comment: No, I don't think associativity is used here. Unless you have a different definition for left and right identities.

Comment: Thank you! Looking over the wiki here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property and seeing your answer helps me understand it better.